# How to integrate Python Pyramid with Cassandra?

Tags: python, web, cassandra, pyramid

I'm starting to code a new application with Pyramid and Cassandra, but I'm unsure how is the best practice to integrate these frameworks. I'll be glad if someone can give me a light. Thank you!

EDIT:

In order to explain better my question, I want know how to keep my session alive through the application. That's better.

Comment: using google, may be?

Comment: I already googled, but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: By now I found a good approach, by using add_request_method, it is working by now, but I need more study regarding its behavior.

Creating the application with starter scaffold, I made the following changes:
`def main(global_config, **settings):
    (...)
    cluster = Cluster(['mycluster'])
    session = cluster.connect()

    config.registry.db = session

    def add_cassandradb(request):
        db = config.registry.db
        return db

    config.add_request_method(add_cassandradb,'db', reify=True)

    (...)`
Of course it needs be improved, but I think I made a good start.

Comment: It works, but very awkward... I'm not sure if connecting all the time is a good thing.